# Constructing a PDFAnnotation

Tags: swift3, quartz-graphics, macos-sierra

mac OS Sierra SDK deprecates PDFAnnotationLink.

I have a pdf page: myPDFPage, bounds for a clickable area in that page: myBounds, and a url that I want to jump to when the specified area is clicked: myUrl. I can assemble these correctly in Swift2, but cannot understand how this is done in Swift3 under Sierra. I am using Xcode 8.0. I am aware of the constants kPDFAnnotationKey_... and have read the Xcode documentation for PDFAnnotation and PDFAction. I have imported Foundation, Cocoa and Quartz into my source file.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Trial code fragment:

```
let newAnnot = PDFAnnotation()
newAnnot.setValue(myBounds, for AnnotationKey: kPDFAnnotationKey_Rect)
let actionDict:[String:Any] = ["/URI":myURL]
newAnnot.setValue(actionDict, forAnnotationKey:kPDFAnnotationKey_Action)
myPDFPage.addAnnotation(newAnnot)
```

or should the actionDict be something like

```
["/S":"/URI", "/URI":myURI]
```

Comment: I do not an answer, as I am not a AppKit Developer (yet), but Apple has a sample application project (it's objective-c, so some translation is required for swift code) for PDF Annotations:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PDFAnnotationEditor/Introduction/Intro.html

Hope it helps :)